# relationship between CPUECTLR.SMPEN, caches and MMU

Tags: caching, arm, mmu

I'm reading ARM document (ARM ® Cortex ® -A57 MPCore Processor) and see the following descriptions about

*You must set CPUECTLR.SMPEN to 1 before the caches and MMU are enabled, or any instruction cache or TLB maintenance operations are performed.*

CPUECTLR.SMPEN is for:

*Enables the processor to receive instruction cache and TLB maintenance operations broadcast from other processors in the cluster.
You must set this bit before enabling the caches and MMU, or performing any cache and TLB maintenance operations.
You must clear this bit during a processor power down sequence.*

However, it is still unclear for me the real reason (i.e., why we should set CPUECTLR.SMPEN to 1 before the caches and MMU are enabled). Please help me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, SMPEN essentially controls whether the core participates in coherency protocols or not.

Without it set, any TLB or cache maintenance operation a core performs will only affect *that core*, and it won't be aware of other cores doing the same, nor of data in other cores' private caches - on an SMP system with all the cores operating on the same regions of memory, this is generally a recipe for data corruption and disaster.

Say everyone has their MMUs and caches enabled, and core A goes to remap some page of memory - it writes zeros to the PTE, invalidates its TLB for that VA, then writes the updated PTE. Core B could also have a TLB entry for that VA: unless the TLBI is broadcast, core B won't be aware that its entry for that VA is no longer valid, and could read bogus data or worse corrupt the old physical page now that it may have been reused for something else.

OK, perhaps core B didn't have that address cached in its TLB, but goes to access it after the update, and kicks off a page table walk. Without [cache coherency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOESI_protocol), this goes several ways:

- Core B happens to have the page table cached in its L1; unless it can snoop core A's L1 to know that someone else now has a dirty copy of that line and its own copy is now invalid, it's going to read the stale old PTE and go wrong.
- Core B doesn't have the page tables cached at L1; unless it can coherently snoop the dirty line from core A's L1, the read goes out to L2 or main memory, hits the stale old PTE and goes wrong.
- Core B doesn't have the page tables cached at L1, but core A's first write has already propagated out to L2 or further; unless core B's read can snoop the second write from core A's L1, it reads the intermediate invalid PTE from L2 and takes a fault.
- Core B doesn't have the page tables cached at L1, but both of core A's writes have already propagated out to L2 or further; core B's read hits the new PTE in L2, and everything manages to work as expected *by pure chance*.

Now, there are some situations in which you might not want this - in *asymmetric* multiprocessing, where the two cores might be doing completely unrelated things, running different operating systems, and working in separate areas of memory, there might be a small benefit from not having unnecessary coherency chit-chat going on in the background - on the rare occasions the cores might want to communicate with each other there, they would probably do so via inter-processor interrupts and a specific shared area of uncached memory. For SMP, though, you really do want the cores to know about each other and be part of the same coherency domain *before* they have a chance to start actually allocating cache lines and TLB entries, which is precisely why the control of all the broadcast and coherency machinery is wrapped up in a single, somewhat-vaguely-named "SMP enable" bit.

To elaborate on actually entering and exiting coherency, when coming in you want to be sure that your whole data cache is invalid to avoid conflicting entries - If a CPU enters SMP with valid lines already in its cache for addresses owned by lines in other CPUs' coherent caches, the coherency protocol is broken and data loss/corruption ensues. Conversely, when going offline, the CPU has to guarantee its cache is clean to avoid data loss - it can prevent *itself* dirtying any more entries by disabling its cache/MMU, but it also has to exit coherency to prevent dirty lines being transferred in from *other* CPUs behind its back. Only then is it safe to perform the set/way operations necessary to clean the whole local cache before the contents are lost at powerdown.

Comment: very valuable information. I still have two questions:
1) In the datasheet "You must clear this bit during a processor power down sequence". Can you explain a little bit?

Comment: I also read another article about SMP enable bit. It is appreciated that if you can help me understanding why PC and LR are zero if the SMP enable bit is not set. Link for that article: https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/4/14/229

Thanks.

Comment: "PC and LR are zero if the SMP enable bit is not set" - no, that's merely a manifestation of data corruption. The task is rescheduled from CPU A, to CPU B, then back to CPU A. Subsequently, it does something like `ldr x30, [sp]; ret`, hits a stale entry in CPU A's TLB (because something was remapped whilst running on CPU B, but the lack of SMP meant CPU A didn't see a broadcast TLBI) which now leads to the wrong physical page, happens to read a zero from there as its return address, and goes bang.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, which are quite reasonable.